# Loading MathJax from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: support, mathjax

I use Windows XP and suddenly MathJax doesn't work at https://math.stackexchange.com/  using Google Chrome or IE.

How can I fix it?   There is a similar question about Windows 7:   http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13230/mathjax-isnt-working-how-to-fix-it Is the answer same? BTW, that answer did not solved my problem.

Comment: We have no way of determining whether you are encountering a similar problem as that other user. If you include more information about your particular situation (_e.g._, a screen shot of any error messages you can find, as described in that other thread; does MathJax work on other sites (such as [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/mathjax/test/))) it will be more likely that someone here could help you.

Comment: in MathJax Test Page it says:mathjax image fonts appear to working

Comment: ctrl+ shift J on my browser results:  "**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)**"  and    "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

Comment: (1) Just the image fonts worked? Not the first page? (2) What resource failed to load?  (3) In retrospect, I didn't send you to the greatest test page. [MathJax's own test page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/) would be much better.

Comment: (1)Now it says in *MathJax Test Page*: "MathJax Appears to be Working!"  BTW i don't know what *first page* is. (3)in  http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/  i can see math equations.

Comment: That "MathJax test page" I first linked to had two versions, one using regular fonts, and one using image fonts (it was also running on an old version of MathJax). The link I gave was to the first, and there was a link to the "image fonts" test on that page. In your comment you said that it responded with "MathJax image fonts appear to be working", which suggested to me that you somehow skipped over the page I linked to. (I apologise if this assumption was incorrect.) I take it that MathJax is still not rendering here. Have you tried something simple like restarting your computer/browser?

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: I'm confused.   i tested "**(such as here))**" in your 1st comment and "**MathJax's own test page**" in 2nd.

Comment: ctrl+ shift J on my browser results   GET http://mathjax-cdn.storage.googleapis.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full 403 (Forbidden)   ucf:43
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: it's **fixed** thank you Arthur Fischer

Comment: Don't thank me. I did nothing. Thank the invisible fairies for exorcising the demons who took over your computer.

Comment: Seems to be a restriction on ips from some countries (Syria,Cuba,..). Try an ip changer.  *We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country* what google may say!

Answer (score 5):

Originally, SE sites loaded MathJax from

```
http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
```

which did not work over https protocol. Two months ago, SE implemented a hack-ish solution: detecting if the client uses  https  and replacing the link with

```
https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
```

See [the announcement](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12549/127096).

On March 17, MathJax Team (represented by Peter  Krautzberger) issued a [call for testing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/Nx42MFg8D9c):

> We have set up a copy of the MathJax CDN on Google Cloud Storage in the hopes of eventually migrating the CDN from Rackspace to GCS.
>
> We'd appreciate it if you are able to try out this copy and report any issues.
>
> The base url (both http and https) is

```
mathjax-cdn.storage.googleapis.com
```

> So for example, http://mathjax-cdn.storage.googleapis.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js will give you the latest version of MathJax. All MathJax versions are available.

Out of the [SE sites using MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/251274), Math.SE was the first to switch to the new copy. This is a much cleaner solution, since the link is protocol-relative.
Most users never noticed the CDN switch: so far we had only two reports, including this one.

If MathJaX does not render, click the above link to MathJax.js. If you get a message saying *We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country*... well, at least you'll know why.

Users should be aware that the current setup is somewhat experimental.

[image: obligatory meme]

Comment: *Update*: for now, the CDN is [reverted back to Rackspace](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13230/mathjax-isnt-working-how-to-fix-it#comment51973_13231)